# AttributeError: 'UserViewSet' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've currently got an API endpoint that works as I would expect it when I send a request to it manually via `Postman`. The way I do so is running:

```
GET /user/?fromid=1&toid=100
```

I am now trying to setup unit tests using `factory-boy` but I'm not able to get it to work due to an error.

So far, the important files with regards to the unit tests that I have are:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"user", views.UserViewSet, basename='user')

urlpatterns = [
    path('user', views.UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'user'}), name='user')
]
```

**test_user.py**

```
import factory
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from factory import DjangoModelFactory, Faker
from models.user import User

class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class UserViewSetTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        client = Client()

    def test_user_list(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('user'), format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

When running `pytest`using the above, I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'UserViewSet' object has no attribute 'user'

I have a feeling that the parameters in the URL aren't allowing me to call it as is from my unit test, but I'm not sure.

As I mentioned, I've been able to send a request via Postman to the API so I'm not sure it's useful to show my complete code (i.e. the ViewSet, models and serializers). For what it's worth, the viewset currently just returns a list of users in Json format.

**EDIT:**

I've been able to recreate the error manually on Postman. If I create a request without specifying the URL parameters, like the following:

```
GET /user
```

I get the same error manually

> AttributeError: 'UserViewSet' object has no attribute 'user'

As a result, I have tried to update my `reverse` command within the unit test to include the URL parameters, as such:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('user'), kwargs={'fromid':1, 'toid': 100}, format='json')
```

But I'm still getting the same original error.

**EDIT2:**

I think part of the problem is with the way I'm calling `reverse`. The `kwargs` parameter wasn't in the actual `reverse` function. I've modified it to be as such:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('user', kwargs={'fromid':1, 'toid': 100}), format='json')
```

Now my error is to do with the url path (I believe) as now I'm getting a new error which is:

> Reverse for 'user' with keyword arguments '{'fromid':1, 'toid': 100}'
> not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['/user$']

My (hopefully final) question is how do I specify multiple parameters in my `path` to accept the kwargs? My endpoint is currently accepted to parameters (fromid and toid) in the URL, so I need to specify that in the `path` elements below. How can I do so?

```
router.register(r"user", views.UserViewSet, basename='user')
    
urlpatterns = [
    path('user', views.UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'user'}), name='user')
]
```

Comment: What is this `user` that you're passing to the url user (inside the `as_view(..)`)?

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues sorry, that was a copy/paste error. It's supposed to be the 'user' name String. I've also edited my question to include further information.

Comment: Open up the shell `python manage.py shell` and try reversing the url. It's probably not what you want. Perhaps the kwargs are for the url...

It'll also help to post your viewset here, coz that's where the error is.

Comment: The url `/user` (fails) is not the same as `/user/` (succeeds), note the trailing slash. `views.UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'user'})` are you sure that view has a method `user`? As that dictionary is supposed to map the request method to the method of the viewset that would be used. Also you never use your router in the code you show us...

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues The thing is, I'm able to send a request manually so I don't believe it may have to do with the view set and rather the test. I've edited my question further.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The view has a method user. I am also able to send a request manually so as I mentioned in my previous comment, perhaps the issue is with the test set up rather than the viewset itself.

Comment: @Adam please show your viewset, also as I said the url `/user` and `/user/` are **not** the same, where do you get the second one? (you don't show it anywhere, also you have a router but never use it in the code you show). Please see how to write a [mre].

Comment: Should your URL look like `/users/?fromid=1&toid=100`? if so doing `self.client.get(reverse('user'), data={'fromid':1, 'toid': 100}, format='json')` might work.

If the URL should look like `/users/1/100/` then the kwargs to reverse are correct, but the url would be `path('user/<int:fromid>/<int:toid>/', views.UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'user'}), name='user')`

Comment: I have a feeling somewhere in your view you are doing `self.user` which makes it fail

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues my URL does indeed look like `/users/?fromid=1&toid=100`. I've tried `self.client.get(reverse('user'), data={'fromid':1, 'toid': 100}, format='json')` but I'm getting the same original error `AttributeError: 'UserViewSet' object has no attribute 'user'`. Do I need to modify how my `path` is in `urls.py`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sure, I will try to show my viewset. Could you tell me what you mean by `/user` and `/user/` are not the same and where I get the second one?

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues I have narrowed down my issue to EDIT2 in my question. Could you have a look please?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have narrowed down my issue to EDIT2 in my question. Could you have a look please?

Answer (score 1):

drf [routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage) will use a name like

> basename+'-list'

for generated url with **list** actions. so your code should be:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('user-list', kwargs={'fromid':1, 'toid': 100}), format='json')
```